# Trying to create LocationManger, but the MKCoordinateRegion doesn't seem to be returning

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit, core-location

I am trying to create a `LocationManager` class that my `ViewModel` will use in a view. I want to be able to use the `checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()` function in my `ViewModel` to be able to get the `MKCoordinateRegion` and initialize it to the `@Published var region` variable in my `ViewModel`. However, the `checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()` function in my `LocationManager` seems to only return a `nil` value. I am struggling to understand why this is the case.

My code:

**LocationManager**

```
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

final class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    static let shared = LocationManager()
    private override init() {}
    
    // Optional because user can have location services in phone turned off.
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion?
    
    func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled() -> MKCoordinateRegion? {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager!.delegate = self
            return region
        } else {
            print("Show alert letting the user know this is off and to go turn it on.")
            return nil
        }
    }

    private func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        guard let locationManager else { return }
        
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Parental controls prevent us from using your location.")
        case .denied:
            print("You have denied location permission.")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate,
                                        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    // Called when locationManager is created, or when authorization is changed.
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {    
    @Published var isSettingLocationManually = false
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 25, longitude: 46),
                                               span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 30, longitudeDelta: 30))
    
    
    func checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled() {
        if let region = LocationManager.shared.checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled() {
            self.region = region
            print("success")
        }
        print("did it work?")
    }
}
```

The function returns a `nil` value. How can I get it to return an `MKCoordinateRegion`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple problems here. You shouldn't be using `!` at all. You need to tell the location manager that you want it to start tracking. Even if you did tell it to start tracking

```
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager!.delegate = self
            return region
        }
```

At this time it would not have a region, because it wouldn't have had the chance to start tracking yet.

I just implemented something very similar in one of my apps, dig through this and you can see how it all comes together.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//
//  Created by Andrew Carter on 12/15/22.
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

// Don't forget to add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to your info plist!

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
 
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    private var continuations: [CheckedContinuation<MKCoordinateRegion, Never>] = []
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func fetchLocation() async -> MKCoordinateRegion {
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuations.append(continuation)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        
        continuations.forEach { continuation in
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate,
                                            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
            continuation.resume(returning: region)
        }
        
        continuations.removeAll()
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
}

@MainActor
class MyLocationProvider: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var region: MKCoordinateRegion?
    private let locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    init() {
        Task {
            self.region = await locationManager.fetchLocation()
        }
    }
    
}



struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var locationProvider = MyLocationProvider()
    
    var body: some View {
        if let region = locationProvider.region {
            Text("Region is " + String(describing: region))
        } else {
            Text("Fetching region...")
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

We can use async await to make a nicer api. You can even constantly publish updates if you wanted to instead of fetching the location just once. Also note that you need `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` defined in your bundle's info plist!

[image]